# s3.upload_fileobj gives error a bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

My question is inspired by a [previous SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404263/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-save-a-large-pandas-dataframe-to-s3) about this topic: uploading and saving DataFrames as csv files in Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3. Using Python3, I would like to use `s3.upload_fileobj` – multi-part uploads – to make the data transfer to S3 faster. When I run the code in the accepted answer, I receive an error message : *"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ".* .

The answer has recently been upvoted several times. So I think there must be a way to run this code without error in Python3.

Please find below the code. Let's for ease use a simple DataFrame. In reality this DataFrame is much bigger (at around 500 MB).

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[6,7,8]})
```

The code is the following. I turned it for convenience in a function :

```
def upload_file(dataframe, bucket, key):
    """dat=DataFrame, bucket=bucket name in AWS S3, key=key name in AWS S3"""
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csv_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(csv_buffer, compression='gzip')
    s3.upload_fileobj(csv_buffer, bucket, key)

upload_file(df, your-bucket, your-key)
```

Thank you very much for your advices!

Comment: Your exact python version?

Comment: Seems like you're using Python 2?

Comment: The Python version is 3.7.1.

Comment: If you continue to get errors, make sure you are using a pandas version greater than 1.2.0 which includes [a fix for supporting bytes for file handles in to_csv()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35129).

Answer (score 9):

Going off [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113172/4909087), it seems you'll need to wrap a `gzip.GzipFile` object around your `BytesIO` which will then perform the compression for you.

```
import io
import gzip

buffer = io.BytesIO()     
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv().encode())
buffer.seek(0)

s3.upload_fileobj(buffer, bucket, key)
```

---

**Minimal Verifiable Example**

```
import io
import gzip
import zlib

# Encode
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[6,7,8]})

buffer = io.BytesIO()     
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv().encode())

buffer.getvalue()
# b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xf0\x0b\x11]\x02\xff\xd3q\xd4q\xe22\xd01\xd41\xe32\xd41\xd21\xe72\xd21\xd6\xb1\xe0\x02\x00Td\xc2\xf5\x17\x00\x00\x00'
```

```
# Decode
print(zlib.decompress(out.getvalue(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode())

# ,A,B
# 0,1,6
# 1,2,7
# 2,3,8
```

Comment: Thank you! I get an error "out" is not defined. Could you give some additional explanation with your code?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart "out -> buffer" sorry, a copy paste typo. I was renaming variables for better clarity. My approach here was to take the IO buffer and wrap it around a GzipFile object. The stream passes through GzipFile and is compressed before it is placed in the buffer. You can then treat the buffer as you would usually. It is similar to what Tarun Lalwani has done except they used a TextIOWrapper and had pandas take care of the compression (either way is fine IMO, they both rely on the same implementation/libraries if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: For some reason, running your code now again leads to an uploaded file of 0 B (empty file). I cannot remember that I had this before. If you have a chance, would you be willing to inspect on your system?, I wonder if it has something to do with a version update of packages.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart ensure you seek to the start of the buffer first.

Comment: Great answer @cs95, in a similar situation, if we have to specify `encoding='utf-8'` in `dataframe.to_csv(csv_buffer, compression='gzip')` instead of `compression`, it gives ` "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"`, how could we overcome this, thanks!

Comment: @pc_pyr I don't see `compression` in my answer, I don't think you need that if you're using `GzipFile`.

Answer (score 2):

The only you need is a TextIOWrapper, as `to_csv` expects a `string` while `upload_fileobj` expects `bytes`

```py
def upload_file(dataframe, bucket, key):
    """dat=DataFrame, bucket=bucket name in AWS S3, key=key name in AWS S3"""
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csv_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    w = io.TextIOWrapper(csv_buffer)
    dataframe.to_csv(w, compression='gzip')
    w.seek(0)
    s3.upload_fileobj(csv_buffer, bucket, key)
```

And the code uploads fine

```sh
$ cat test.csv
,A,B
0,1,6
1,2,7
2,3,8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The script works but there is an issue. Comparing s3.upload_fileobj (using io.BytesIO and your TextIOWrapper solution) with s3_resource.Object (using io.StringIO) I observed something remarkable. When DF was relatively small, the s3.upload_fileobj method was faster. However, when the DF has more rows (for ex > 200K), the s3_resource.Object became fastest. Importantly, both remain painstakingly slow. Any suggestions for faster big file upload to S3?

Comment: If you decide to keep it all in the memory for a larger chunk it may not give you performance, so best would be dump to a temp file and then upload the file

Comment: Do you mean upload temp files to S3, and all temp files should be merged at S3?

Comment: What I mean is that keeping everything in memory in case of larger files won't help. So the best thing is to save the files to disk and then upload. If merge is required you can merge on the disk itself. Instead of using python I would use the OS `cat` command for the same

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[6,7,8]})

def upload_file(dataframe, bucket, key):
    """dat=DataFrame, bucket=bucket name in AWS S3, key=key name in AWS S3"""
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(csv_buffer, compression='gzip')
    csv_buffer.seek(0)
    s3.upload_fileobj(csv_buffer, bucket, key)

upload_file(df, your-bucket, your-key)
```

Comment: now it is giving the error "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"